# Configuring stp port fast bpdu root guard

Tags: spanning-tree

How do you configure spanning tree port fast bpdu root guard on cisco 3560 switch? Can anyone tell me if there's any difference in the configuration of stp port fast bpdu root guard in cisco 3560 and 2960 switches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `spanning-tree portfast`, and `spanning-tree bpduguard enable` on each switchport.  Root guard is unnecessary on ports with this configuration, because bpduguard will err-disable the port when you receive any bpdus.

Use root guard on links to other switches, which are not planned for the primary or secondary stp root role.

Comment: Matter of personal preference, but on any newer platform (2960 or later), I use `spanning-tree portfast bpduguard default` in global configuration.  This automatically applies to any switchport with portfast enabled, which is generally what I want.  You can then do a `spanning-tree bpduguard disable` on the ports where you don't want it.

Comment: @YLearn Agreed, in fact, most organizations explicitly require those as default parameters.

Answer (score 0):

As an aside and since I cannot leave comments yet, I prefer to use `switchport host` when setting up access ports. The `switchport host` command is a macro on all Cisco switches. it sets the port up as an accessport, spanning-tree portfast, and disables etherchannel capabilities.

Once you've used the `switchport host` command your can then run whatever additional commands are needed such as `spanning-tree bpduguard enable` or `spanning-tree bpduguard enable`.